# When making a PL/SQL block via oracle, is it possible to create a table and then modify that table in the same block?

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is related to a lab for class. The professor's wording seems to imply we are supposed to do everything in go.

```
DECLARE
    c_xyz NUMBER(10);
    v_counter1 INT;
    string_a varchar2(50);
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE theater(row_name NUMBER)';
  COMMIT; --tried with and without this
  DECLARE
    v_row_number theater.row_name%TYPE; --ERROR table does not exist yet
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SEQUENCE list# INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1';
  END;
END;
```

Comment: You could resort to dynamic PL/SQL where you build the entire PL/SQL block and dynamically execute it.  That gets a little complicated to manage and maintain but it's certainly doable.  Practically, though, it's very unusual to create tables at runtime and very, very unusual that you'd want to reference that new table in the same PL/SQL block.

Comment: @JustinCave I agree this is unusual. The professor worded his labs weird and doesn't give straight answers when asked. I think I am just going to create the tables and such outside the block, then use the block to modify the code.

Comment: I would do the same, and - to put it bluntly - if the professor didn't like it, I wouldn't give a damn. It seems that, even though you are a student, you are sensing (correctly) that - unless you misunderstood the requirement - the requirement itself is flawed. As Justin Cave said, this is not something that a sane developer would ever need to do, or consider doing. Do this the best way **you** think it should be done, see if you can have a meaningful discussion with the guy, but if you can't, it's not on you, so don't take it too hard.

Comment: @mathguy **is completely correct**. However you need to keep in mind that the professor (or assistants) will pass judgement on you - in the form of a grade. So no matter how utterly ridiculous the requirement seems you must satisfy it. Or it is you not they that suffer the consequences. I once had to remind my son this. But he was stubborn and wanted to prove it could be done differently and he did;. after which he repeated the class the next semester. So keep your instincts and  try to have that meaningful discussion. In the end however you must do it their way.